# Использование Whatsapp в своём приложении

Tags: java, android, api, whatsapp

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ встроить в своё приложение вход,  отправку и получение сообщений от Whatsapp?

Comment: Да, это возможно, если у WhatsUp есть API, открытое для сторонних разработчиков и если оно имеет необходимые возможности.

Comment: На сколько мне известно, таких нет. Поэтому я спрашиваю, есть ли обходной метод?

Comment: Судя по тому, что видно на первой странице выдачи гугла - есть только сторонние платные решения (сомнительной легальности). Либо нужно вручную отследить запросы к API и повторять их пока WhatsApp их не заблокирует и, опционально, не подаст иск в суд, т.к. без их разрешения делать это, по идее, незаконно. Получается, что короткий ответ на ваш вопрос - нет, использовать WhatsApp самостоятельно - нельзя, если вы не крупная компания с прямым договором с WhatsApp.

Comment: @Игорь а [это](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api?lang=ru) тогда что?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev это не то, что я ищу. В моих интересах сделать возможным вход в приложение для каждого пользователя со своего личного аккаунта Whatsapp. А Buisness Api это по сути аккаунт организации.

Comment: Такого не предоставляет ни один из популярных мессенджеров, на сколько мне известно.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev из тех, которые я знаю - Вк, Telegram

Answer (score 0):

Как понял речь про oAuth. Именно протокола нет, НО не сложно сделать подобное через api где можно подгружать данные о пользователе. Делаем ссылку на wa.me/{номер вашего аккаунта с ботом}?text={любой идентификатор входа выглядящий как приветственное сообщение}, как только получаем сообщение на бота мы надежно верифицируем человека, пишем ему приветствие и либо предлагаем ссылку для возврата на сайт, либо сайт сам отслеживает статус авторизации. Я делал подобное через ChatAPI на трех проектах, т.к. все сообщения входящие, то с банами не сталкивался. Можно еще  попробовать сделать через официальный API, но с ним я не работал.